# Auto complete removes data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a piece of code to get to get customer details using autocomplete. It's returning the data and I can see it, but when I try to save the data (click on save button) it removes the text box data and it becomes empty.

Code behind :

```html
   $(".custid").autocomplete("../Ajax/get-customer-list.aspx", {
                width: 330, selectFirst: false, scrollHeight: 90, mustMach: true
            });
            $(".custid").result(function (event, data, formatted) {
                if (data) {
                    $(".custid").val(data[1].trim());
                    $(".cusname").val(data[0].trim());
                    $(".cusmobile").val(data[2].trim());
                    $(".txtOther").focus();
                }
            });
```

and on the controls.

```html
   <div class="label-item">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Search Name"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
             
                    <div class="control-item>">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustID" runat="server" CssClass="custid" Width="126px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="cusname"  ReadOnly="True" Width="280px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="label-item">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Customer Name"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
             
             
                         
                    <div class="control-item">                                        
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustName" CssClass="cusname" runat="server" Width="150px" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>

                    </div> 
                     <div class="clear"></div>
                     <div>
       
     </div>
                    <div class="label-item">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Mobile Number"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-item">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomerMobile" runat="server" cssClass="cusmobile" Width="201px" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                            <div class="label-item">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-item">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Width="201px" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Your save button is posting back to the server and it is rebuilding the page, without the dynamically fetched auto-complete data. In other words, it is working as ASP.NET WebForms was designed (destroy the page on each postback and rebuild it, based upon the code in the `Page_Load` event). Check in your browser's developer tools to see if there is an error when the page reloads (i.e. when it is trying to call the server-side to fetch the auto-complete data).

Comment: True , but how i can save the data. Button click should post back right. how i can solve. No i have no error.

Comment: you need to have a client-side function that intercepts the save button click event and "grabs" the data from the auto-complete and then have the server-side click code execute once you have finished "saving" the auto-complete choice made by the user. I think you need to post your "save" button ASP.NET click handler code in order to have someone help you move further along.

Comment: save button code is checking lot of data and i cant change the code. what i done is now , i took the custid and create one stored procedure to bring the data from table and save it. its working so far no error and data is correct. Really thanks for your replies.